# Cannot run notebooks in datalab when connecting via Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-shell

For years we have been connecting to our datalabs via Google Cloud Shell.

Recently, when connecting to the datalabs we are able to connect as always without error but once inside the datalab are unable to run any of the notbooks. The files are visible but they cant be run.

We have been able to get around this issue by connecting to the datalabs via our local SDKs which appear to not have the same restrictions. We would however like to again be able to do this entirely via Cloud Shell.

Any ideas on what to try?

I have attempted to delete and reinstall the gcloud component for datalabs in Cloud Shell but we get the same result.

Comment: Can you please submit in-product feedback about this issue?  Use the 'Feedback' option under the triple-dot menu.  Thanks.